# How to enable analytics in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, analytics, azure-devops-server-2019

Azure devops has in-built analytics support.I tried to pull some extensions for enabling analytics in on premise TFS without much luck.  How analytics can be  enabled in on -premise TFS?

Comment: First of all, you need Azure DevOps Server 2019. Then install the extension from the marketplace: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/analytics/analytics-extension?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analytics works with Azure DevOps Server 2019 (formerly Team Foundation Server) and it requires the [Analytics extension to be installed separately](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-analytics):

[image]

So if you're on TFS, you'll have to upgrade to Azure DevOps Server 2019. Apart from the name, this is just Team Foundation Server 2019 and it has nothing really to do with Azure.